# Trying to generate TLS 1.3 Alert

Tags: tls, web-application, webserver, nginx

I am trying to run tests on the TLS 1.3 protocol and I would like to generate alerts (as seen in TLS 1.2) that have a structure of the type ALERT:FATAL UNEXPECTED MESSAGE.

So far, I have tried to use fuzzers, load generators, and custom scripts to generate alerts, but I honestly can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

Could someone help me clear up my ideas? Do I need to do anything different than when I was generating alerts for TLS 1.2?